Deploy metadata passed as a bash variable
i have a bash variable that contains paths and it looks like this:
metadata=$(cat file.txt)

where the file.txt contains paths such as
"module/main/default/class/someclass.cls" "module/main/default/layouts/some layout with spaces.xml" "module/main/default/flexipages/someflexi.xml"
all in a single line with a space between each other.
I am then passing this variable to a command such as:
sf project deploy start -o myorg -d "$metadata"

but this is returning the following error:
Error (EfError): "module/main/default/class/someclass.cls" "module/main/default/layouts/some layout with spaces.xml" "module/main/default/flexipages/someflexi.xml" : File or folder not found

Why is that happening?
The module path is included in the sfdx-project.json too.
I used to the same procedure without any "" around the paths which worked fine besides for the layout which having spaces in the path made the command fail, that's the reason why i changed to using ""

Running...
sf project deploy start -o myorg -d "foo" "bar"

the error message (pointing out that these files don't exist) refers to foo and bar rather than to "foo" and "bar". The arguments are stripped off their double quotes.
After replacing the variable metadata (of your question) with what it is supposed to represent, sf treats it as a single entity - the error message you cite contains all the double quotes.
I suggest to use xargs. xargs correctly identifies the arguments listed in the file:
xargs -a file.txt sf project deploy start -o myorg -d

(Tested on Windows Subsystem for Linux, GNU bash 4.4.23.)

This worked, thanks a lot.
In the end tho i used another method to get the metadata i needed, using a plugin for the sf cli that creates a package.xml file to then deploy the metadata throuh that one.
Your answer its still very helpful, cheers
